# why is the .loc() function returning an empty Series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, and i want to use the .loc() function in pandas for conditional extraction in the 'Fare' and 'Name' columns in the dataframe.

```
quest = data.loc[data['Fare'] == 512.329,  'Name']
```

But when I run this and try to figure out the name responsible for the fare in the 'Name' column, i get an empty series returned.

```
Series([], Name: Name, dtype: object)
```

How do I fix this and get the Name?

Comment: Are you sure that there a rows of `data['Fare']` that equal `512.329`?  Remember that float representation can be imprecise in ways that make it hard to isolate a value like this.  Maybe show us a (small) sample of your dataframe with the value that you're trying to isolate?  See [mcve].

Comment: Try `np.isclose(data['Fare'],512.329)` instead of `data['Fare']==512.329`

Comment: @Chris the np function worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the condition `data['Fare'] == 512.329` is not verified, and in my opinion it could be a type mistake. Please verify your `512.329` is a float (and not a **string**)

```
for i in data['Fare']:
    print(type(i))

# desired output :
# <class 'float'>

# unwanted output :
# <class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of 'Fare' in the DataFrame data? Probably it is not a float. If it is a string then  `data['Fare'] == 512.329` will not return any results.

First check the type of `data['Fare']`, by executing

```
data['Fare'].dtype
```

If it is `dtype('O')` either convert it to float by executing

```
data['Fare'] = data['Fare'].astype(float)
```

or make your query using a string like this

```
quest = data.loc[data['Fare'] == '512.329',  'Name']
```

Comment: Its a type 'float 64'